# PHP code causing "deprecated" error in PHP 5.3

Tags: php

The following code causes a 'deprecated' error in PHP 5.3... Is there a substitute for it?

```
$this->widgets[$widget_class] = & new $widget_class();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd be nice if you could specify what *exactly* the error message says, but I'm guessing it's informing you that object assignment by reference (`=&`) is deprecated. Objects are *always* assigned and passed by reference as of PHP 5, so including `&` is unnecessary. Simply drop the reference operator:

```
$this->widgets[$widget_class] = new $widget_class();
```

Comment: I don't think "assignment by reference" in general is deprecated but  "new object" assignment is. See http://php.net/manual/en/migration53.deprecated.php - *"Assigning the return value of new by reference is now deprecated."*

Comment: @Phil Good link, I was looking for a reference (no pun intended) in the manual, but couldn't find one.

Comment: Same, had to use Google as I didn't think to look in the migrations section